# Increase probability of lava lakes spawning in a superflat world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I'm making a nether map that involves the use of superflat world presets. The ground is completely netherrack, and there are lava lakes spread across the map. I'm running into a problem though, the lava lakes don't spawn often enough for me and I want them to be more common. Here's the base preset I'm working off.

```
2;1x7,30x87;8;lava_lake
```

Now, this just creates a superflat world with lava lakes here and there, not that common. Now, here are a few things I tried to make lava lakes more common.

```
2;1x7,30x87;8;lava_lake(chance=100)
2;1x7,30x87;8;lava_lake(size=10 distance=0)
```

None of these seemed to increase the probability of a lava lake spawning. So, how can I increase the probability of lava lakes spawning?

Comment: Is this on creative?

Comment: @stizzle84 Yes, but I don't believe that gamemode affects how the world generates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using a later snapshot (at least 14w21b I believe), as it has lots more world generation options. It allows you to change almost anything about generation, so you could create a whole overworld that is nether themed.

[image: World Settings]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in any snapshot after 14w26a I believe, as I could not find the hell biome option on the biome slider.